# How to read variables from an external file?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to learn Python and at this point, I am very confused.  Here's what I'm attempting to do:

I have a Python script that needs to call variables from an external file.  The external data file cannot reside in the same folder as the Python script. The location of the data file is currently `/Users/discoveryone/Documents` (this will be running on a Macintosh). Here's the contents of the data file:

```
domains='apple.com', 'google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'aol.com', 'disney.com', 'mydomain.com', 'hotmail.com'
email='noone1@nowhere.com'
smtpserver='smtp.mydomain.com'
smtpport='465'
smtpto='noone1@nowhere.com'
smtpfrom='noone2@nowhere.com'
```

I need to call the all of the values in the `domains` field and then process them through a while loop individually and use the other data if need be.

Can someone please help me to call the external data file into my Python script?

Comment: You should use configparser https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Comment: Answered your question, hope it was helpful! Welcome to SO! Please consider marking it as correct if it helped you.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel This forces the user to follow the INI structure of configparser.

Comment: where is your python script contents? please include any of your code attempt so we can further advise. thanks

Comment: Did you write any line of code yet? If yes, post it in your question.

Comment: Downvotes without comments aren't useful..

Comment: Then please write so in comment. Not useful at all to just rage and downvote. This creates  a community that seems hostile and isn't particularly constructive while being so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file is called `file.txt`, you can add all those variables to the `global` `scope` with:

```
with open("/Users/discoveryone/Documents/file.txt") as f:
    for l in f:
        var, val = l.split("=")
        globals()[var] = val.strip().replace("'", "")
```

and then you could access `email` for instance and it would have the value:

```
'noone1@nowhere.com'
```

---

The only problem with this is that `domains` is only a `string` of the `domains`:

```
'apple.com, google.com, yahoo.com, aol.com, disney.com, mydomain.com, hotmail.com'
```

to convert this to a list of `domains`, simply add the `line`:

```
domains = [d.strip() for d in domains.split(",")]
```

which will modify `domains` to:

```
['apple.com', 'google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'aol.com', 'disney.com', 'mydomain.com', 'hotmail.com']
```

Comment: Please notice this answer does not create an iterable of domain values which is what OP wants.

Comment: @alexisdevarennes Sorry man, I was just getting to that bit, added it now!